# Insert blank form

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a form in Word and protected everything except the form fields.

[image: Layout so far]

I want to add the form without any user inserts on the next page, so the user can fill the form for another device.

EDIT: also is there a way to exclude not filled form fields from the print?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Word macros using VBA (read more here). To insert new page to your document, you can run this code:

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

To better understand how to work with Word and VBA refer to this page, it might be very helpful as a start point:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604039(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: ok I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to add just a blank page. I want to add the form (like in the pic) without any user inserts on the next page, so the user can fill the form for another device. Thx I'll check your link